# Depth First Search Efficiency

Tags: ruby, algorithm, binary-search-tree, depth-first-search

I have implemented a DFS method which takes in a search value and a Binary Search Tree as arguments. The method then searches the tree for the given value, returning it when found.

When I call the method, there appears to be a duplicate node visit which may be affecting the efficiency. Is this visit in fact a duplication or just a reflection of the nature of DFS?

For instance, if my binary tree looks like the one below and I'm looking for the the value 3, the search is popping the 5 node off the stack, then the 2, then the 1, then *retrieving the 2 node from the stack again* before finding the 3. Is this stack retrieval of the 2 duplicative? Is it a proper DFS?

```
     5
    / \
   /   \
  2     7
 / \   / \
1   3 6   8
     \     \
      4     9
```

#### Binary Tree

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :left, :right

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end
end

def build_tree(array, *indices)
  array.sort.uniq!
  mid = (array.length-1)/2
  first_element = indices[0]
  last_element = indices[1]

  if !first_element.nil? && first_element >last_element
    return nil 
  end

  root = Node.new(array[mid])
  root.left = build_tree(array[0..mid-1], 0, mid-1)
  root.right = build_tree(array[mid+1..-1], mid+1, array.length-1)

  return root
end
```

#### Depth First Search Method

```
def depth_first_search(search_value, tree)
  stack = [tree]
  visited = [tree]

  while !stack.empty?
    current = stack.last
    visited << current
    puts current
    p current

    if current.value == search_value
      puts current
      exit
    elsif !current.left.nil? && !visited.include?(current.left)
      if current.left.value == search_value
        puts current.left
        exit
      else
        visited << current.left
        stack << current.left
      end
    elsif !current.right.nil? && !visited.include?(current.right)
      if current.right.value == search_value
        puts current.right
        exit
      else
        visited << current.right
        stack << current.right
      end
    else
      stack.pop
    end
  end
  puts "nil"
end
```

#### Method Call

```
binary_tree = build_tree([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
depth_first_search(3, binary_tree)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, since it is DFS, it works that way. DFS in a binary-tree works exactly like `pre-order traversal` of the tree. So, for the example tree in the figure, DFS would be visiting like:

```
5-2-1-(2)-3-4-(3)-(2)-(5)-7-6-(7)-8-9
```

Here, the values in brackets is the "second visit" that you are calling, but, it does not actually visit those nodes. So, it is alright.

Also, I'd recommend using a `binary search` if the input tree is BST (not DFS).

Comment: Thanks @vish4071. I was tasked with implementing a DFS as part of a project. I'll take your advice about using a `binary search` for use in the future.